# Can you send a message that an object won't catch?

Tags: objective-c

I'm reading this book and it says that this code will compile but cause a runtime exception. But when I run it on my computer it doesn't compile: "No known instance method..."

```
#import "Fraction.h"
int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{
     @autoreleasepool {
     Fraction *f = [[Fraction alloc] init];
     [f noSuchMethod];
     }
   return 0;
}
```

My question is when does doing this cause a runtime exception and when does it cause a compile-time warning?

Comment: Have you compiled and ran it?

Comment: yes, it doesn't even compile

Comment: @andrew_ghobrial: A missing method generates a warning, not an error, so either you have enabled treat warnings as errors, or there is another compilation error.

Comment: i meant compile-time warning and runtime exception (to be precise)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compile-time error is because the selector `noSuchMethod` does not appear on any class the compiler has seen. Under ARC, the compiler cannot safely decide how to apply memory management rules in that case (it could try to follow standard naming conventions, but that could lead to extremely difficult bugs if the selector were declared with alternate semantics in some other header). It is also almost certain a mistake, so the compiler rightfully balks at guessing. (There is another issue related to the return type, and before ARC the compiler would guess about that, but it generally wasn't what you wanted even if it happen to guess right most of the time.)

<strike>If `-noSuchMethod` were known to exist on *some* class, but not `Fraction`, then the compiler would issue a warning. At runtime, if `f` failed to respond, you'd get a runtime exception.</strike> (This was the old behavior; it seems that clang may have gotten a bit more strict in my experiments and will throw an error now in this case, too. This may be the confusion with your book if it was written before the change, or the author has not rechecked it in a while.)

If `noSuchMethod` were known to exist, but `f` were declared of type `id`, then no warning would be generated. At runtime, if `f` failed to respond, you'd get a runtime exception.

Comment: so it seems that if it's declared as id then it will check to seed if the method is in the interface of ANY class before compiling. if it's declared as Fraction (its real type) then it will check to see if the method is in its interface. So a runtime exception is caused by having the method in the interface but not the implementation!

Answer (score 1):

It depends ...

When you use ARC then, per default, the compiler will throw an error for a method call when the method name is not known at compile time. 
When you don't ARC then you get a warning only at compile time.

You can, however, customize the warning/error level of the compiler to get is passed in both cases.

Objective-C binds method calls during runtime. If you manage to get it compiled then you could even react on the runtime error right before the exception is thrown and dynamcially register a method during runtime under the name of `noSuchMethod` and actually perform some code when ever the method is invoked in the future during the same runtime session. It is probably this behaviour of dynamic binding during runtime that the autor of your book is trying to explain by example.

Comment: how do I not use ARC? by getting rid of the @autoreleasepool directive?

Comment: Frankly I am not sure. When ARC was introduced you had an option when creating a new project in xcode. I am not 100% positive if that option is still around as I am using ARC ever since. The autoreleaspool is fine, regardless of ARC or not.

Comment: i found it in build settings and disabled it to see what would happen. just like you said. thanks!!